# Linear system of 4 differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this system of differential equations?

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
K_1 & K_2 & K_3 & K_4\\
T_1 &T_2 & T_3 & T_4 \\
\end{array}
\right)*\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a' \\
 b' \\
 c' \\
 d' \\
\end{array}
\right)+\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 A_1 & A_2 & 0 & 0 \\
 B_1 & B_2 & B_3 & B_4 \\
 0 & 0 & C_3 & C_4 \\
 0 & 0 & D_4 & D_4 \\
\end{array}
\right)*\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a \\
 b \\
 c \\
 d \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
E_1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$ K, T, A, B, C, D, E$ are constants.

**Update:** I edit the differential equations, it was my mistake

Comment: Where are the fourth order equations ??

Comment: Chances are high that this problem statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your system has the form

$$A\mathbb y'=\mathbb b$$ or

$$\mathbb y'=A^{-1}\mathbb b,$$ trivially solved by integration as

$$\mathbb y(t)=A^{-1}\mathbb b\,t+\mathbb y_0.$$

---

**Update:** (after OP fixing the question)

The system has the form
$$A\mathbb y'+B\mathbb y=\mathbb b$$

but due to the special structure of $A$, the first two equations are ordinary, so that $a,b$ can be expressed linearly in terms of $c,d$. Before adressing the differential part, eliminate $a,b$ and write the remaining two equations in the form

$$Pz'+Qz=r$$ where $\mathbb z=(c,d)$ and $P,Q$ are $2\times2$ matrices, or

$$\mathbb z'+P^{-1}Q\mathbb z=P^{-1}\mathbb r.$$

Now, the general solution of the homogeneous equation is

$$\mathbb z=C e^{-P^{-1}Qt}$$ where the exponential of the matrix can be obtained from its Eigenvalues.

A particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation is constant, given by

$$\mathbb z=Q^{-1}\mathbb r.$$

You combine these results to get the complete solution and plug the initial conditions to determine the matrix $C$.

Comment: Isn't it of the form $Ay'+By=c$? Edit: oh right, OP has edited the question to change it.